# "Quick brown fox..." equivalent in Spanish?

Tags: alfabeto

In typing classes in English, it is common to learn to type the sentence:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Because it contains every letter of the alphabet at least once.

Is there an equivalent Spanish language phrase or sentence that can be used for typing practice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That kind of sentences which uses a every letter of the alphabet at least once are called **pangrams** (in Spanish "pangrama") or **holoalphabetic sentence** (in Spanish "frase holoalfabética"). There is even [a wikipedia entry about them](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangrama).

In that entry you can find these examples:

> - Cada vez que trabajo, Félix me paga un whisky (36 letters) (Ñ is missing)
> - Cada vez que me trabo, Félix paga un whisky añejo (39 letters)
> - Extraño alijo hampón: güisqui; kiwi, vid y ... ¡¿bizc8?!. (38-41 letters) Rich format: –«€xtraño @lijo hampón: güisqui(º); kiwi,
>     vid y … ¿¡“bizc8”!?»
> - ¡Ávida cigüeña floja!, pibonazo quemó whisky extra. (41 letters)
> - Extraño alijo ampón: whisky/güisqui, bizcocho, vid... (41 letters)
> - Quiere la boca exhausta vid, kiwi, piña y fugaz jamón. (42 letters)
> - Fabio me exige, sin tapujos, que añada cerveza al whisky. (45 letters)
> - Jovencillo emponzoñado de whisky, ¡qué figurota exhibe! (46 letters)
> - David exige plazo fijo para el embarque de truchas y niños New York. (55 letters)
> - La cigüeña tocaba cada vez mejor el saxofón y el búho pedía kiwi y queso. (58 letters)
> - El jefe buscó el éxtasis en un imprevisto baño de whisky y gozó como un duque. (62 letters)
> - El cadáver de Wamba, rey godo de España, fue exhumado y trasladado en una caja de zinc que pesó un kilo. (81 letters)
> - El pingüino Wenceslao hizo kilómetros bajo exhaustiva lluvia y frío, añoraba a su querido cachorro. (83 letters)
> - Wendy pidió que se le añadiera a su compra cerveza, un bote de jugo de frutas y un kilo huesos de la carnicería anexa. (91 letters)
> - El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocaba el saxofón detrás del palenque de paja. (92 letters) (Used for displaying an example of the typography in Windows and Linux in Spanish)

Maybe you can find much more by just looking for pangram or pangrama in google. [Wikipedia also has another list of them in every language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams).